# mysql access denied eventhough grant permission exists

Tags: mysql, database, mariadb

I have created user and grant all permissions, but still not able to connect to the sql using it. Could someone kindly help resolving this?

Steps followed
    mysql --user=root  mysql;

```
CREATE USER 'db_user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password'; 
CREATE USER 'db_user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password'; 
CREATE USER 'db_user'@'hostname' IDENTIFIED BY 'password'; 
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'db_user'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION; 
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'db_user'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'db_user'@'hostname' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

When I try to connect like

```
mysql -u db_user -ppassword -h 'hostname'
```

I get this error

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'db_user'@'hostname' (using password: YES)

MariaDB [(none)]> show grants for db_user@'hostname';

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'db_user'@'hostname' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*2470C0C06DEE42FD1618BB99005ADCA2EC9D1E19' WITH GRANT OPTION 
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

What is it missing that it is not letting to connect?

Comment: `using password: YES` - your password is wrong...

Comment: hash of password matches 2470C0C06DEE42FD1618BB99005ADCA2EC9D1E19. what could be wrong?

Comment: You've created 3 users, though it looks like you're connecting remotely. Do all 3 users have the same password?

Comment: correct. all of them have the same password.

Comment: Where you have `'db_user'@'hostname'`, is `hostname` the hostname of the address you're connecting **from**?

Comment: that's right. it is the local host name.

Comment: unless you want to grant `*.*` and with `WITH GRANT OPTION` (for sure), I would not do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you confirm again that the hostname is the `hostname` of the local host?

Can you try these.

```
DROP USER 'db_user'@'localhost';
DROP USER 'db_user'@'%';
DROP USER 'db_user'@'hostname';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'db_user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*2470C0C06DEE42FD1618BB99005ADCA2EC9D1E19' WITH GRANT OPTION;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'db_user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*2470C0C06DEE42FD1618BB99005ADCA2EC9D1E19' WITH GRANT OPTION;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'db_user'@'hostname' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*2470C0C06DEE42FD1618BB99005ADCA2EC9D1E19' WITH GRANT OPTION;

mysql -u db_user -ppassword -h `hostname`
```

Comment: just recreating the user

Comment: hostname is the name of the local host.

Comment: can you paste the o/p of `hostname` command and also the exact command that you are executing

Comment: what DBHash is doing is good. It cleans the server out of 3 potentially problematic rows. A `select user,host,password from mysql.user where user='db_user' order by 1,2` wouldn't be a bad idea :>

Comment: DBHash suggestion worked. may I know what was the issue and why did we drop the users and just grant permission? Thanks all for your help.